# jQuery using $(this) and hover together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/xpvt214o/460806/)

I am trying to use $(this) keyword & jquery's hover() function.

There are 3 divs with class 'item', each div contains two child divs, 'trigger' & 'trigger-box', what I am trying to achieve is when user hovers on each 'trigger' div, 'visible' class needs to be added to it's respective 'trigger-box'.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 3</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$('.item').hover(function() {

    console.log("hover in");
    $('.item .trigger-box', this).addClass('visible');

  }, function() {

    console.log("hover out");
    $('.item .trigger-box', this).removeClass('visible');;
});
```

I've tried with multiple combinations '$(this)' keyword but couldn't get it to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you specifically need to add the class, or do you simply need to style the `.trigger-box` element based on hovering over the `.tirgger` element (which can be achieved with CSS)?

Comment: I just need to affect the styling of 'trigger-box' element based on hover state of '.trigger'. I was wondering it could be done with CSS since they both are siblings not parent and child.

Comment: Effectively `.tirgger:hover + .trigger-box { /* styles here */ }` - or charlietfl's approach - should work for a CSS approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `.item` part of

```
$('.item .trigger-box', this);
```

That syntax is the exact same process as

```
$(this).find('.item .trigger-box')
```

But since `this` **is** the `.item` it will not find that selector. It's looking for itself *inside* itself

[Working version](https://jsfiddle.net/savyf45x/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
$('.tirgger').hover(function() {

    $(this).parent().find('.trigger-box').addClass('visible');

  }, function() {

    $(this).parent().find('.trigger-box').removeClass('visible');;
});
```

```css
.visible {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="tirgger">
      <h5>Trigger 3</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger-box">
      <h3>trigger box 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.trigger-box').css("opacity","1")
},function(){
    $(this).find('.trigger-box').css("opacity","0");
});
});
```